# Mysql Workbench-Connection Warning- incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol detected (10.1.19)

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost, mysql-workbench, database-connection

[MYSQL Connection warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zws4.png)

> ***Incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol detected (10.1.19). A connection to this database can be established
>   but some MYSQL Workbench features may not work properly since the
>   database is not fully compatible with the supported versions of MYSQL.
>   MYSQL Workbench is developed and tested for MYSQL Server version 5.1,
>   5.5, 5.6 and 5.7***

As you can see I wanted to make a connection with my database named [ assignment-3-client-accounts ].

I got this warning ! 
Can anyone please help me why I am getting this warning and How I can solve this warning!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server should be running MySQL version 5.1, 5.5, 5.6 or 5.7, with 5.7 and 5.6 being the most preferred versions. A lot of hosts will set you up with 5.4 because they still live in 2006 apparently. Upgrading your servers MySQL version to 5.6 or 5.7 *should* solve that.

If it's not that, then it's most likely due to your server running MariaDB, which is the drop in replacement for MySQL. They are *very* similar, but have a few differences and that will most likely cause MySQL Workbench to give you a warning that not *all* features will work. I've read of people going back to MySQL from MariaDB to fix this, but that's actually a bad idea and a lot of work just to stop a tiny warning popup.

In most cases like this you can just press "Continue Anyway" and keep working as normal.